# Is possible create a simple game with background scroll to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, apple-watch

I am developing a simple game for Apple Watch, and I doubt I'm the following:

You can do a simple background of infinite scrolling in Apple Watch. It would be a simple game style run.

I will use the SpriteKit.

May indicate some tutorial will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use SpriteKit with the Apple watch. Read the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH8-SW1) to find out what you can do.

Comment: It is possible to create a game that style using some framework?

Comment: @Tiago - Look at some of courses offered by Udemy. They might give you some good ideas on what can be done and what you can use. https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&q=watchkit